# How can I draw a curve which satisfies several definite integrals?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given data like the following:
[image: probability bar chart]

I would like to draw a curve with the property that integrating over the intervals of the bars (e.g. 04:00 - 07:00) will give the same answer as that given by the bar chart (in this case, 62).

I was planning to do this using numpy and scipy. I had a play with the interpolation library, but decided it wasn't what I was after.

Does anyone know of a tool or algorithm for making such a curve?

Comment: What does mean "data like following"? Is it constant or linear on intervals, or it is arbitrary? If it is arbitrary you need to interpolate it with admissible algorithm for your purpose and integrate with another one. If data is linear on intervals, you can explicitly calculate the area.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question wasn't clear. The data is constant on each interval, it's basically a bar chart. So explicitly calculating the area is fine. What I'm not sure how to do is find a continuous function with the same area in each intervals.

Comment: @prdnr Continuous would be simple, but you probably want a differentiable one?

Comment: @G. Bach Quite right, I'd like a differentiable function!

Answer (score 2):

Let's figure out the linear system for computing the coefficients of a piecewise quadratic curve. Let there be `n` bars, where bar `i` (counting from `0`) extends from `x[i]` to `x[i+1]`, with height `y[i]`. Piece `i` is the quadratic function

```
lambda z: a[i]*z**2 + b[i]*z + c[i]
```

where `a[i], b[i], c[i]` are coefficients. We get `n` equations fixing the area.

```
a[i]*(x[i+1]**3 - x[i]**3)/3 + b[i]*(x[i+1]**2 - x[i]**2)/2 + c[i]*(x[i+1] - x[i])
    == y[i]*(x[i+1] - x[i]) for i in range(n)
```

We get `n-1` equations matching up the values at boundaries.

```
a[i]*x[i+1]**2 + b[i]*x[i+1] + c[i]
     == a[i+1]*x[i+1]**2 + b[i+1]*x[i+1] + c[i+1] for i in range(n-1)
```

We get `n-1` equations matching up the derivatives at boundaries.

```
2*a[i]*x[i+1] + b[i] == 2*a[i+1]*x[i+1] + b[i+1] for i in range(n-1)
```

There are two more degrees of freedom. We could, e.g., require that the beginning and ending derivatives be zero.

```
2*a[0]*x[0] + b[0] == 0
2*a[n-1]*x[n] + b[n-1] == 0
```

Use NumPy to solve these equations (this probably involves turning this system into a matrix).

Comment: I don't immediately see that that system would always have a solution since it's not homogeneous. Will this always have solutions, and if not, would using piecewise quartic curves help? I'm having trouble figuring out what happens if we get too "high" at the end of one interval and can't go down without breaking differentiability.

Comment: @G.Bach I haven't thought about how to prove that the equations always have a solution, but just from algebraic geometry, it's clear that "too high" won't be a problem -- the problem will be measure zero if this algorithm works at all.